# MongoDB Auditing vs. Profling

Tags: mongodb, audit

I wanted in the first place to log connections to a collection and while I was searching I found that it's possible to configure profiling and auditing and logging.

So my question is : *What's the difference between the 3 and when to use which?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profiling collects information about "what, when and how information was queried + how much time it took + what was DB engines solution"

Auditing tell "who did what and when" (who red/accessed f.ex. user information)

Logging is higher level information telling what DB did and when. When client makes/closes connection, new index is created, data is replicated, engine errors happened...

So, if law says that "we need to know who (as a person) accessed specific information", you do auditing.

To find out "which queries are slowest/take time and WHY" you use profiling.

To know what's happening and what are errors on database level, you use log files.